# can't figure it out how to calculate total score from user's answer

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Code in question. Answers from drop down list (see picture)**[this is how user interface looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODiqy.jpg)

**Full code below. Total score should be calculate from value of all answers. Each Answer has value (int) and text**

Each answer choice is a dictionary with keys of value and text. These correspond to an int and a string, respectively.

```
class PersonalityQuiz extends React.Component {
    state = {
        score: 0,
        myAnswer: null,
        answers: []
    };
//I assume this part is the problematic one
    handleShowScore = e => {
        const { myAnswer, answers, score } = this.state;
        if (myAnswer === answers) {
            this.setState({
                score: score + answers.value
            });
        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Quiz</h1>
                <p>Select your favorite of each of the following choices:</p>
                <div>
                    {qData.map((item, index) => (
                        <li key={index}>
                            {item.question}
                            <select>
                                {item.answers.map(answers => (
                                    <option value={answers.value}>{answers.text}</option>
                                ))}
                            </select>
                        </li>
                    ))}
                </div>
                <button onClick={this.handleShowScore}>Show Score</button>

                <p id="score">You total score is {this.state.score} points.</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**and JSON data**

```
const qData = [
    {
        id: 0,
        question: "question 1",
        answers: [
            { value: 1, text: "rafael" },
            { value: 2, text: "dontaelo" },
            { value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
            { value: 4, text: "michelangelo" }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        question: "question 2",
        answers: [
            { value: 1, text: "rafael" },
            { value: 2, text: "dontaelo" },
            { value: 3, text: "leonardo" },
            { value: 4, text: "michelangelo" }
        ]
    }
];
```

Comment: What is the initial value of ```answers``` in the state?

Comment: it should be 0. 
class PersonalityQuiz extends React.Component { state = { score: 0, myAnswer: null }

Comment: You are destructuring ```answers``` in ```handleShowScore```, but I don't see ```answers``` initiated in the state. What is the value of ```answers``` and ```myAnswer``` in the ```if condition``` in ```handleShowScore ```?

Comment: I see. Empty array. answers: [ ]

Answer (score 0):

In your `handleShowScore`, you are comparing `myAnswer === answers` `(null === [])`, it return falsy value so the statements inside `if` will not be ran. So `this.state.score` is always 0. On the other hand, `answers` is an array, but you are using `answers.value`, it's not right.

Comment: yeah it looks messy. will try to figure it out. thanks for looking into it

Comment: I reworked handleShowScore and now have different issues, such as cannot read property length of identified in for loop:                                                
            handleShowScore = () => {
  var i, newScore;
  var a = qData.answers;
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
   newScore = newScore + a[i].value;
  }

  this.setState({
   score: newScore
  });
 };

Comment: @PinkFloyd Check again ```qData.answers```, it's not an array so you can not use ```.length``` property.